# Bottom table border not showing when last row and previous rows has a cell with rowspan and a different border color

Tags: html, css

I have some borders of style `double`, while some borders of style `solid` according to my precedence requirements. These styles are for different colors of border of `<td>` in my table.

This is an example table:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px double #000;
}

td {
  border: 1px double #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is that the bottom border of table is not showing completely. Note that I can't change style from `double` to `solid` for given `<td>` because I am already using them for other `td` classes (see EDIT).

## EDIT

The `rowspan` can be any number.

Here is the complete `SCSS` file:

```
$dark-black-grey: #212121;
$black-grey: #616161;
$dark-grey: #bdbdbd;
$medium-grey: #e0e0e0;
$light-grey: #eeeeee;
$blue-grey: #b0bec5;
$light-blue-grey: #cfd8dc;
$white-grey: #fafafa;
$blue: #64b5f6;
$light-blue: #90caf9;
$white-blue: #bbdefb;
$green: #81c784;
$red: #e57373;
$light-red: #ef9a9a;
$white-red: #ffcdd2;
$light-yellow: #fffde7;
$font-size: 14px;
$header-height: 30px;
#data-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 4fr;
  div {
    height: 100vh;
    &:not(:last-child) {
      border-right: 1px double $dark-grey;
    }
    div.table-wrapper {
      height: calc(100% - #{$header-height});
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
      table {
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px double $dark-grey;
        tr {
          &:first-child {
            td {
              border-top: 0;
            }
          }
          &:last-child {
            td {
              border-bottom: 0;
            }
          }
          td {
            border: 1px double $light-grey;
            padding: 4px 8px;
            &:first-child {
              border-left: 0;
            }
            &:last-child {
              border-right: 0;
            }
            &.fade {
              color: $black-grey;
            }
            &.footer {
              text-align: right;
              font-weight: 500;
            }
            &:not(.warning):not(.info) {
              &.computed {
                background-color: $light-yellow;
              }
              &.optional {
                background-color: #ffeeff;
              }
              &.input-box {
                background-color: $white-grey;
                &:hover {
                  background-color: $light-grey
                }
              }
            }
            &.warning {
              background-color: $light-red;
              input {
                background-color: $light-red;
              }
              &:not(.button) {
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: $light-red;
              }
              &.button {
                background-color: $white-grey;
                &:hover {
                  background-color: $white-red;
                  border-style: solid;
                  border-color: $white-red;
                }
                &:active {
                  background-color: $light-red;
                  border-style: solid;
                  border-color: $light-red;
                }
              }
            }
            &.info {
              background-color: $light-blue;
              input {
                background-color: $light-blue;
              }
              &:not(.button) {
                border-style: solid;
                border-color: $light-blue;
              }
              &.button {
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: 500;
                background-color: $white-grey;
                &:hover {
                  background-color: $white-blue;
                  border-style: solid;
                  border-color: $white-blue;
                }
                &:active {
                  background-color: $light-blue;
                  border-style: solid;
                  border-color: $light-blue;
                }
              }
            }
            &.button {
              cursor: pointer;
              padding: 4px;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      &.popup {
        position: absolute;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 1px $black-grey;
        td {
          background-color: white;
          padding: 4px 8px;
          cursor: pointer;
          &:hover {
            background-color: $light-grey;
          }
          &:active {
            background-color: $medium-grey;
          }
        }
      }
      &.header {
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px double $dark-grey;
        height: $header-height;
        tr td {
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: 500;
          padding: 0 4px;
          &.fade {
            color: $black-grey;
          }
          &.button {
            cursor: pointer;
            &:hover:not(:active) {
              background-color: $light-grey;
            }
            &:active {
              background-color: $medium-grey;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
svg {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: $font-size;
  height: $font-size;
}
input {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px $blue
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px $green;
    &.invalid {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px $red
    }
  }
}
td.shrink {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Add 2px border in table..

Comment: I don't want that

Comment: Is the inner value always "2"?

Comment: No, the value can be any number, check my solution also and see if there are any cases the solution won't work

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px double #000;
}

td {
  border: 1px double #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

td[rowspan="2"] {
  border-bottom: 1px double #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: If this does not help you we need 2 more things from you.

- **All** of your `CSS` / `HTML` code, not just a snippet
- To know if you are willing to use `JavaScript` or  `JQuery` to solve your issue

See the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwro2xzq/)

Comment: The rowspan can be any number, my `CSS` (actually `SCSS`) file is actually a long one (200 lines), tell me if I should post... I am using `Reactjs` by the way. The table is just one of the components.

Comment: You can use `border-bottom: inherit` for the rowspan bottom border so the border style doesn't need to be duplicated.

Comment: It might be an idea to post it. Thoughts on using JS or JQuery?

Comment: Ok, I am posting my `SCSS` file. I am using `React`, so I can use `js`, but no `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

add the below css

```
td[rowspan="2"] {
  border-bottom: 1px double #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pure `CSS` solution. Not sure if it works for all cases because of the precedence among other `<td>` with `solid` borders, but didn't find any such cases till now.

```css
td[rowspan]:not([rowspan="1"]) {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```